# how to subset data with all factors existing of one variable?

Tags: r

I have 4 variables: student Id, semester that they attend (maximum 3 semesters), their some sort of activities (act) and the date when the activities occur. Since some students only took one or two semesters, is that a way to subset the data with students attending all 3 semesters using R? Thanks very much! The data look like:

```
ID        date     act  semester
123256  11/1/2015   105 2015Fall
123256  10/1/2014   1   2014Fall
123256  10/1/2015   4   2015Fall
123256  9/1/2016    48  2016Win
545454  12/4/2015   64  2015Fall
545454  10/4/2015   49  2015Fall
545454  9/4/2014    66  2014Fall
545454  12/5/2015   66  2015Fall
545454  10/5/2014   57  2014Fall
224821  10/13/2015  35  2015Fall
224821  12/14/2015  130 2015Fall
224821  11/14/2015  55  2015Fall
224821  10/14/2015  6   2015Fall
633443  10/17/2015  26  2015Fall
633443  9/17/2015   60  2015Fall
633443  12/18/2015  204 2015Fall
633443  11/18/2016  114 2016Win
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need to subset the students ("ID") that attend 3 'semester', we can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', `if` the `length` of `unique` elements is 'semester' is 3 (`uniqueN` - is a wrapper for `length(unique(.))`), we subset the dataset (`.SD`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(semester)==3) .SD , ID]
#         ID      date act semester
#1: 123256 11/1/2015 105 2015Fall
#2: 123256 10/1/2014   1 2014Fall
#3: 123256 10/1/2015   4 2015Fall
#4: 123256  9/1/2016  48  2016Win
```